# Métodos de Interfaces con Funcionamiento

Tags: java

Muy Buenas , gracias por leer. Estoy aprendiendo el vasto , extenso lenguaje de java. y he tenido una duda. -Metodos de interfaces con funcionamento..

he estado aprendiendo que las interfaces son por asi decirlo directrices que han de llevar las clases que implementen esas interfaces, pero hace unos dias he visto varias interfaces que tienen funcionamiento en sus metodos sin haber sido sobre escritos por ninguna otra clase que yo sepa..

si alguien pudiese ayudarme en esto seria grandioso ya que es de las pocas cosas que aun no he entendido de java.

saludos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El concepto de Interface lleva un paso más alla el concepto de una clase abstracta, una clase abstracta es una clase que no se puede instanciar (crear un objeto de esa clase) pero sí se pueden definir atributos e implementar métodos en ella para que sus clases hijas los puedan utilizar (Lo hereden).

> Pues bien, una Interface es una clase abstracta pura en la que todos
>   sus métodos son abstractos y por tanto no se pueden implementar en la
>   clase Interface.

¿Entonces para qué vale una clase abstracta pura en la que no se permiten implementar métodos y que encima en las clases hijas de esa interface tengan que tener "si o si" implementados estos métodos?

Pues bien, las Interfaces sirven para establecer la forma que debe de tener una clase. Un ejemplo que hay en Java sobre Interace es la Interface Map. En concreto los HashMap, TreeMap y LinkedHashMap, lo que quiere decir que todas las clases Map deben de tener implementadas a su manera los mismo métodos como el "put()", "get()", "remove()", etc. Se ha establecido una forma común que deben de respetar todos los Maps de Java.

Por otro lado se puede decir que en una Interface no se pueden definir atributos salvo que estos sean estaticos o constantes; es decir, "static" o "final".

> Ahora después de esta pequeña intro, se puede decir que en **Java 8**
>   se ha incluido el método **"default"**  que se puede implementar en la
>   clase interface y que su implementación será común para todas las
>   clases que implementen esa interface.

Dicho así, uno puede pensar que con este método se rompe con la premisa de que las clases interface son abstractas puras, pero la inclusión de este nuevo método en las interfaces de java 8 tienen dos propósitos interesantes como son:

1. No modificar las clases que usen esa interface.
2. Simular una "Seudo Herencia Múltiple", ya que java no dispone de
   herencia múltiple como tal.

El punto 1 tiene bastante sentido y más hoy en día en que es muy importante la rápida respuesta al cambio, ya que suponer un caso en el que hayamos desarrollado una interfaz que la implementan 20 clases y necesitemos a última hora añadir una nueva funcionalidad que deben de tener todas las clases que implementan nuestra interface. Pues en este caso con implementar un método "default" en la interface nos valdría para solucionar el problema y adaptarnos rápidamente al cambio.

Espero haberte aclarado un poco el asunto.

Un saludo.